# Understanding contour function in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I have the following sets:

```
x = 
 [[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]
 [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.]]

y=
[[-0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9 -0.9]
 [ 0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.1]
 [ 1.1  1.1  1.1  1.1  1.1  1.1  1.1  1.1]
 [ 2.1  2.1  2.1  2.1  2.1  2.1  2.1  2.1]
 [ 3.1  3.1  3.1  3.1  3.1  3.1  3.1  3.1]]
```

and

```
Z = 
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
 [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]]
```

I have `colors = ('red', 'blue', 'green')` and when I use matplotlib to draw the contour with `plt.contour(x, y, Z, colors=colors)`, I get:

[image]

I was expecting to only have three lines dividing the 0 area from the 1 area from the 2 area. Why do I have so many?

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib` has interpolated between your points so that the z-value changes more gradually. You can see this by plotting your `x` and `y` values as dots (`pyplot.plot(x[i][j],y[i][j],'ok')`, looping over `i` and `j`). If you do this, you'll see that the lines all fall between the dots, so they actually do separate the area into three regions.

You can specify which lines to show using the `levels` keyword argument:

```
pyplot.contour(x,y,z,levels=[.5,1.5])
```

(you only need two lines to separate these three areas.)

If you want to look at the matrix elements without interpolation, you can use matshow:

```
pyplot.matshow(z)
```